# BroadcastReceiver when highlighting a word

Tags: android, android-intent, action, intentfilter

with Android you can react to Actions like Outgoing Calls (New_Outgoing_Calls) or other Actions.
I want to react to the Action when someone highlights (marks) a word, but I don't know what action is used then. I would imagine that it is something like New_Highlighted_Text, but that is only a guess :(

Does anybody know this ?

Tschüss, Andre

Comment: The frameworks' text editing feature is "in-app" only and does not broadcast externally. However if you want to receive these events inside your own application it might be possible. Request and I'll post details.

Answer (score 0):

This page, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html contains all the `Intent` class constants.

You should look over there.

Though in a quick look I haven't found a constant for what you're looking so it may not be available or at least not available in that way.